# Using the Server Explorer GUI(VS) is there a way to create a one to many relationship between tables for a SQL CE 3.5 database?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, user-interface, sql-server-ce, one-to-many

Using the Server Explorer GUI(VS) is there a way to create a one to many relationship between tables for a SQL CE 3.5 database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Server Explorer, right clikc the table in question, select "Table Properties"and the select "Add Relations" or "Manage Relations"

Comment: i have tried that but i seem to end up with a one to on instead of a one to many